# Cannot install lxml via pip

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, lxml

I want to install lxml via pip, but it just stops, without any error or sth. When I execute

```
pip install lxml -vvv
```

i see, that it stops in the line:

```
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/include/libxml2 -Isrc/lxml/includes -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c src/lxml/lxml.etree.c -o build/temp.linux-armv6l-2.7/src/lxml/lxml.etree.o -w
```

I can leave the console for an hour. Nothings happens. No error message. Nothing.

P.S.: Yes,

```
libxml2-dev libxslt-dev python-dev
```

are all installed.

Comment: armv6l? What platform and exact OS is this running on?

Comment: Raspberry Pi with Wheezy Raspbian.

Comment: It's not a compile machine. It might ake that long. Maybe you are more happy with the OS package. AFAIR it's `python-lxml`,

Comment: Makes sense. That is possible, indeed. Thanks for your answer and time.

Comment: It takes a while on my laptop so on the pi it could take quite a while to compile, the apt-get version is going to be a few releases behind the latest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all people finding that question with the same problem: Compiling processes are very slow on the Raspberry Pi. It just doesn't have enough power. Just don't do that, it's no fun.

Answer (score 0):

Why that didn't work is very simple. Compiling Python's lxml package takes just a little more RAM than you have allocated for it. The default swap space of 100MB plus 512MB RAM means that gcc and kswapd literally fight against each other. It will probably stay at lxml.etree.c until the end of days.

**How to proceed:**

First we identify what is consuming a lot of memory

```
ps aux | head -1; ps aux | sort -rnk 4 | head -5
```

and temporarily terminate corresponding demons and processes.
After that, we expand the swap file to 2GB.

```
sudo dphys-swapfile swapoff
```

to turn swapping off.
Then edit `/etc/dphys-swapfile` and modify the variable *CONF_SWAPSIZE*:

```
CONF_SWAPSIZE = 2048
```

run

```
dphys-swapfile setup
```

which will create and initialize the file.

```
sudo dphys-swapfile swapon
```

to turn swapping on again.

---

I needed this for Home Assistant as it calls for Python 3.8 and that is not in the package feed.

On my Raspberry Pi Zero

```
pip3 install lxml
```

took approx. 70min.